# Intercept web request for playframework an /address that does not exist

Tags: scala, playframework

How can I intercept all web requests to playframework ( have all requests to /something or /other redirected to a same controller ) and in that controller get the calling address path (ex. /something or /other )?

So I can use it to load different environment settings based in the requested path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by just adding a "catch-all" route as **last** route (in your `routes` file):

```
GET /*path controllers.Stuff.catchAll(path)
```

You can also do it for a specific path:

```
GET /something/*path controllers.Stuff.somethingCatchAll(path)
```

The path variable passed to your controller is the actual path. From the controller, you can also inspect the request object as always to get more details.

relevant doc: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Dynamic-parts-spanning-several-/